# unable to login in raspberry.. please help me out

Tags: raspbian, raspbmc

I changed in setting under sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard XKBLAYOUT="in"

I know i made some mistakes here "in" is not any standard but after rebooting my system am unable to login in my device please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a computer running linux you can mount the sd card partition and simply change the setting from there.

The preinstalled rasbian sd-cards uses ext4 for the system partition so you probably won't be able to do this using windows.

Answer (score 2):

How are you trying to login, via your keyboard connected to the device or via a shell?

If you have ssh running on the Pi and it is connected to your home internet connection, then log into your routers page (usually something like 192.168.1.1) and find the IP# that has been assigned to the RPi.

You can then see if the ssh service is started - try ssh pi@
(Assuming pi is your login).
If you get a shell, try your password and hopefully you can log in. You should then be able to edit the keyboard configuration and re-start the Pi.